# $_2F_1\left(\frac34,\frac54,2,x^2\right)$ in terms of elliptic integrals $E$ and $K$

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I am given the following formula (found to be correct numerically):
$$
_2F_1\left(\frac34,\frac54,2,x^2\right) =
\frac{-8}{\pi x^2}
\left[
\sqrt{1+|x|}~E\left(\frac{2|x|}{1+|x|}\right)-
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|x|}}K\left(\frac{2|x|}{1+|x|}\right)
\right]
\quad(|x|<1),
$$
where $_2F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function, and $E$ and $K$ are the elliptic integrals.

Where can I find a formula or clue in mathematical tables?

Thank you for viewing, and help me please.

Comment: Could you precise what and where is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This formula is referenced on WolframAlpha :
http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/09/21/03/0037/

and confirmed :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hypergeometric2F1%283%2F4%2C5%2F4%2C2%2Cx%5E2%29&x=0&y=0